# select count query take 2 mins for count result in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using `mysql` database,its table name  is `license_csv` ,and it has `18 million` records, and it is using `MYISAM` engine when i try to count record without where condition it take less than 1 sec for count, but when i applied where condition it take `2 min` for count result, i have applied `indexing` for that 2 columns `lic_state` and `lic_city`, still it take 2 min for the count result, can anyone please help me what i need to do now for that query ? here i also added my query,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total 
from license_csv WHERE 
lic_state like '%ca%' AND lic_city LIKE '%fresno%'
```

Comment: Why do you need wildcards to select the city and state in a table with 18 million rows.  You should know what these columns contain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that you are using the `%` wildcard on both sides of the string. This defeats an existing index. Because indexes are sequential, MySQL is not able to use them for this type of condition, since there is nothing to tell him where the *start* searching.

Possible options :

- if possible, switch to equality instead of `LIKE`; you could then takd advantage of an index on `(lic_state, lic_sity)`
- else, removing the wildcard on the left side (`lic_state like 'ca%'`) could help
- switch to `FULL TEXT` search
- store the list of CA codes and cities in another table (which should *much* smaller than the licences table), and have a column in the licences table referrencing its primary key; then `JOIN` that table in the search. With this option, the range of records to search when applying the search condition will be mch smaller

Comment: i tried all that option still it is taking long time

Comment: @NikulPanchal... Really? For example, the first option with equality (with the appropriate index in place) should be must faster than the existing query.

Comment: first option is faster than my query but still it take 1 min

Comment: How about the last option, using another table. Did you try that?

Comment: It take 3 min to load result